# point transform from rotation and translation in python

Tags: python, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all. the python tf api has a function for transforming stamped points but i can't find anything to transform a point with just a rotation and translation...

there is a function for returning a matrix from the translation and rotation... is this the only way of transforming such a point?

cheers, Garrick.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195134/point-transform-from-rotation-and-translation-in-python/) by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason is that you need *stamp* (time and initial frame) information to transform a point into a different frame, otherwise it has no context. If you want to apply the transform directly, just apply the same operations as the [transformPoint function](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/bee989f3f4ab39e7ecf5c1bfe61d73d255b84c69/tf/src/tf/listener.py#L98), using the 4x4 matrix.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0